# Compare two image data using unsafe method

Tags: c#, wpf, unsafe

I am writing a function to get difference between two bitmap images in visual studio 2010. I have a function that takes two bitmap images as parameters, I use unlock bits to get data of each pixel,both the images are of equal resolution and dimensions.

When I use  unlock bits for only one image it works well, but when I use it for both simultaneously in the same function it gives an exception

> BITMAP REGION IS ALREADY LOCKED

**code**:

```
    public Bitmap Invert(Bitmap b,Bitmap c)
    {

        BitmapData bmData = 
            b.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, b.Width, b.Height),
                       ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, 
                       System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

       int stride = bmData.Stride;
        System.IntPtr Scan0 = bmData.Scan0;

        // for image 2
       BitmapData data2 = 
           c.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 
                                                   0, 
                                                   c.Width,
                                                   c.Height),
                      ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
                      System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

      int  stride1 = data2.Stride;
        System.IntPtr Scan1 = data2.Scan0;
        unsafe
        {
            byte* p = (byte*)(void*)Scan0;
            byte* q = (byte*)(void*)Scan1;
            nOffset = stride - b.Width * 3;
            nWidth = b.Width * 3;
            for (y = 0; y < b.Height; ++y)
            {
                for (x = 0; x < nWidth; ++x)
                {
                    p[0] = (byte)(p[0]-q[0]);
                    ++p;
                    ++q;
                }
                p += nOffset;
                q += nOffset;
            }
        }

        b.UnlockBits(bmData);
        c.UnlockBits(data2);
        return b;
    }
```

Comment: WPF? Why not use `WriteableBitmap` instead of `System.Drawing` types?

Comment: Please tell us what the result of `object.ReferenceEquals(b, c)` returns at the beginning of the method.

Comment: it crashes at 
BitmapData data2 = 
           c.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 
                                                   0, 
                                                   c.Width,
                                                   c.Height),
                      ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
                      System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

Comment: Are you quite sure you're not accidentally passing the same bitmap for both `b` and `c`?

Comment: Please add the code where Bitmaps b and c are created and passed into the Invert method.

Comment: ya both images are different with slight change
i have used separate bitmap variables for both

Comment: @shadow Please show the code where you create them. Just because you have two different "variables" (e.g. references) to Bitmaps, does not mean they are not the same objects or do not share the same underlying bits.

Comment: thanks for the help, i got it
its working

Answer (score 0):

Becuase you only need to compare images , I would suggesst opening them in read mode only i.e:

```
BitmapData data2 =   c.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 
                                               0, 
                                               c.Width,
                                               c.Height),
                    ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
                    System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
```